# Testing a Foreach<TSource> function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, foreach, ienumerable, mstest

Hello Guys I have to test the next function but since I just start with programming in C# I am stuck, I was reading the whole day about IEnumerables and Enumerators but I can't make the unit test for this function yet.

here is the function

```
public static void ForEach<TSource>([NotNull] this IEnumerable<TSource> source, [NotNull] Action<TSource> action)
{
    Contract.Requires(source != null);
    Contract.Requires(action != null);

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

I call the function like this but it's not working..

```
[TestMethod]
public void ForEach_Test()
{
    //PREPARE
    List<string> listToBeTested = new List<string>();
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");

    //EXECUTE        
    List<string> listformatted = new List<string>();
    listToBeTested.ForEach(listformatted.Add("any string"));

    //ASSERT    
    Assert.AreEqual(listToBeTested, listformatted);
}
```

Comment: Please, don't even write that function. It violates good functional programming principles by creating side effects. There's a reason it's not included in the base framework. Just use a regular `foreach ( ) { }` loop.

Comment: `List<T>` already has a `ForEach()` method which the call is resolving to. Whilst I agree with @JoelCoehoorn, if you absolutely *have* to do this, name it something different. OR, declare your list as `IList<string> listToBeTested = new List<string>();` instead since the `IList<T>` interface doesn't expose `.ForEach()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to test, but I can take a guess help you out with the syntax.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ForEach_Test()
{
    //PREPARE
    List<string> listToBeTested = new List<string>();
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");
    listToBeTested.Add("Any string");

    //EXECUTE

    List<string> listformatted = new List<string>();
    listToBeTested.ForEach(x => listformatted.Add(x));

    //ASSERT

    Assert.AreEqual(listToBeTested, listformatted);


}
```

Now, listToBeTested is the source parameter in your ForEach. For every item in the listToBeTested, the action called will be the lambda we are passing. The variable x represents the item in the lambda, so what is executed will be something like:

```
    foreach (var item in listToBeTested)
    {
        listformatted.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Steve!